# Finding the joint probability density function of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I have a set $Y$ of independent random variables and a set X of random variables which are not necessarily independent, and we know that $P_{Y_i | X_i}(y_i | x_i) = e^{2|\theta x_i - y_i|}$, where $\theta$ is not known, how would one go about finding the joint PDF of the y_i's conditioned on the x_i's?

Honestly, I feel like the question is awkwardly posed. I *assume* it means the joint PDF of  $P_{Y_1 | X_1}(y_1 | x_1),  P_{Y_2 | X_2}(y_2 | x_2),$ and so on, but even then I would not see how to go about finding any expression that is of any use. I'm inclined to say it's simply the product of each conditional probability, but seeing as only the $y$'s are independent, I'm not sure if that would be true. Any help is appreciated and I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: To conclude that $P(Y_1,...,Y_n|X_1,...,X_n)=\prod_{i}P(Y_i|X_i)$ one needs the extra assumption that the set of variables $Y$ is independent of the set of variables $X$. Otherwise there is no simple way to find out the form of the distribution.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thanks for the answer. The question simply states that all the $y$'s are independent. Is there another way of interpreting the question? Here is exactly how the question is phrased, in case I missed something: write the expression for the PDF of the $Y^{(i)}$'s conditioned on the $x^{(i)}$'s (where $i = 1, ... , m$). Could this be asking for the joint PDF of each conditional? Or does that not make any sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Ah, wait. The notation $P(Y | X)$, where $Y$ and $X$ are sets of variables simply means the PDF of $P(Y = y_1 | X = x_2)$, $P(Y = y_1 | X = x_2)$, ... , $P(Y = y_n | X = x_n)$ right? And if I do not know that that $Y$ is independent on $X$ I can't go any further than that? Even with the equation given in my original question? Thanks.